# How to add brackets to each item in a list?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make a method that adds a bracket to each item in a list, e.g `'(h e l l o)` will become `'((h) (e) (l) (l) (o))`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(map list '(h e l l o))
```